# Colorize, Transparent and Move Selected Entities on Xbim Control

Tags: .net, transparency, helix-3d-toolkit, ifc, xbim

I want to Colorize, Transparent and Move selected ifcElements in xbim control.

If xbim control does not support  move, colorized and transparency, I would be very grateful if you could write a sample code to implement these via the helix viewport.
Thanks for all helps

I found this code for transparency but it makes the entire model transparent;

`DrawingControl.Dispatcher.Invoke(Function() DrawingControl.ModelOpacity = 0.1 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100) End Function)`